# Blender 2.91.2 Transparency Effect no longer works with emission

Tags: texturing, transparency, emission

I use emissions to create flat renders, and I used this node layout in Eevee for images with alpha channels.

[image: provided by another blender users]

The above was provided to me by another user.

I've recently updated 2.91.2 and now I can no longer use this lay out. In the current image I'm using, I'm trying to render a checkerboard tile where the white spaces are transparent.

[image]

The original texture is png with alpha channel [image]

But when I apply the same node layout I get a weird interpretation that isn't even transparent.

[image]

It instead creates a weird grid like wireframe effect. Why is this? Did they change how this works or am I doing something visibly wrong.

EDIT: I also went back to an older file, and the effect still works, UNTIL I apply it to a new mesh. By that I mean, copy and paste. Same image, same nodes, no alpha channel. HOWEVER if I use material copy via CTRL+L it does work. I am completely at a loss

Cheers!

Comment: check when you press n in the material editor > options, if blend mode is set to alpha blend or alpha hashed.

Comment: I just looked at the image and your blend mode is set to opaque, which will render alpha to black.

Comment: Yeah I think that solved it.

Comment: if you solved it, in order for people to find this answer when they search for it, answer your question and tag it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from a helpful person

"check when you press n in the material editor > options, if blend mode is set to alpha blend or alpha hashed. – Alex bries"